# How to edit the MBR in multi Boot scenraio?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, mbr

I am currently using Lenovo Y 50 laptop with multi boot: Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10. Day before yesterday, I installed the windows update and now whatever option I select in the Boot Menu while booting the PC, it goes straight to the Windows 10. I searched in the Bios, and the mounting point for both the OS are same. So I figured that my MBR got corrupted and I need to fix the Ubuntu mounting point.

I am unable to enter the Grub command line to edit the MBR. can someone please help me out with this issue? Erasing the partition after taking the data backup and reinstalling Ubuntu has to be my very LAST option. I want to fix it without doing that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If an UEFI system, then it does not use MBR but an ESP - efi system partition. Windows update reset secure boot and its always on hibernation or fast start up. Make sure you change those settings. Can you directly boot Ubuntu entry in UEFI? Also if UEFI do not use EasyBCD.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options available, all of them work but I just don’t like the Windows bootloader as I prefer my custom boot via grub.

1. Install EasyBCD in Windows and use the Windows boot-loader

   Or
2. You can boot from a  Live CD/USB and install the Grub Boot-Repair Tool

   In the terminal type in the following command:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```

   The Grub Boot Repair Tool is Graphical Interface tool which is very easy to use.

   Or
3. [The third option is to use the Terminal to repair the Grub boot. Visit this link to get the full overview](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)